# I have an issue booting my system, what can I do to fix it?

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I cannot boot into Linux or Windows now.

I did the boot repair but every time I turn my computer on it goes to Windows then into recovery mode and I went through that and it still brings me back.

I can only get in Ubuntu through the live disc.

This is my paste:

```
   Boot Info Script 0.61.full + Boot-Repair extra info      [Boot-Info August 2nd 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos5)/boot/grub on this drive.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /BOOTMGR /BOOT/BCD

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe 
                       /ubuntu/winboot/wubildr /ubuntu/winboot/wubildr.mbr

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /boot/grub/core.img

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1               2,048    36,866,047    36,864,000  27 Hidden NTFS (Recovery Environment)
/dev/sda2    *     36,866,048    37,070,847       204,800   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda3          37,070,848 1,120,164,979 1,083,094,132   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda4       1,120,165,886 1,953,523,711   833,357,826   5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1,120,165,888 1,945,663,487   825,497,600  83 Linux
/dev/sda6       1,945,665,536 1,953,523,711     7,858,176  82 Linux swap / Solaris


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        701C63931C635360                       ntfs       PQSERVICE
/dev/sda2        967CF34F7CF3291F                       ntfs       SYSTEM RESERVED
/dev/sda3        761E26E71E269FDB                       ntfs       Acer
/dev/sda5        ab063406-c2b4-49fc-94c7-d91c1592faff   ext4       
/dev/sda6        49b9ffb8-d013-4b78-9027-09e8ce95682b   swap       
/dev/sr0                                                iso9660    Ubuntu 12.04 LTS amd64

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/loop0       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
/dev/sr0         /cdrom                   iso9660    (ro,noatime)


=========================== sda5/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
set default="Windows Recovery Environment (loader) (on /dev/sda1)"
if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}

function load_video {
  insmod vbe
  insmod vga
  insmod video_bochs
  insmod video_cirrus
}

insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,msdos5)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ab063406-c2b4-49fc-94c7-d91c1592faff
if loadfont /usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2 ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  insmod part_msdos
  insmod ext2
  set root='(hd0,msdos5)'
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ab063406-c2b4-49fc-94c7-d91c1592faff
  set locale_dir=($root)/boot/grub/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=10
else
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
if [ "${linux_gfx_mode}" != "text" ]; then load_video; fi
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-29-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos5)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ab063406-c2b4-49fc-94c7-d91c1592faff
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-29-generic root=UUID=ab063406-c2b4-49fc-94c7-d91c1592faff ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-29-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-29-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos5)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ab063406-c2b4-49fc-94c7-d91c1592faff
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.2.0-29-generic ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-29-generic root=UUID=ab063406-c2b4-49fc-94c7-d91c1592faff ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-29-generic
}
submenu "Previous Linux versions" {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-23-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos5)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ab063406-c2b4-49fc-94c7-d91c1592faff
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic root=UUID=ab063406-c2b4-49fc-94c7-d91c1592faff ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-23-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos5)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ab063406-c2b4-49fc-94c7-d91c1592faff
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.2.0-23-generic ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic root=UUID=ab063406-c2b4-49fc-94c7-d91c1592faff ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic
}
}
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos5)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ab063406-c2b4-49fc-94c7-d91c1592faff
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
}
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos5)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ab063406-c2b4-49fc-94c7-d91c1592faff
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry "Windows Recovery Environment (loader) (on /dev/sda1)" --class windows --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 701C63931C635360
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
menuentry "Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda2)" --class windows --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(hd0,msdos2)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 967CF34F7CF3291F
    chainloader +1
}
menuentry "Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda3)" --class windows --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(hd0,msdos3)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 761E26E71E269FDB
    chainloader +1
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sda5/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=ab063406-c2b4-49fc-94c7-d91c1592faff /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=49b9ffb8-d013-4b78-9027-09e8ce95682b none            swap    sw              0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda5: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

 862.277381897 = 925.863288832  boot/grub/core.img                             1
 862.279846191 = 925.865934848  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 536.071788788 = 575.602700288  boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic               2
 537.271041870 = 576.890388480  boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-29-generic               2
 862.270248413 = 925.855629312  boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic                  1
 536.492904663 = 576.054870016  boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-29-generic                  1
 536.071788788 = 575.602700288  initrd.img.old                                 2
 536.492904663 = 576.054870016  vmlinuz                                        1
 862.270248413 = 925.855629312  vmlinuz.old                                    1


ADDITIONAL INFORMATION :
=================== log of boot-repair 2012-08-16__02h01 ===================
boot-repair version : 3.18-0ppa47~precise
boot-sav version : 3.192-0ppa5~precise
glade2script version : 0.3.2.1-0ppa7~precise
boot-sav-nonfree version : 3.18-0ppa10~precise
W: Duplicate sources.list entry cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)/ precise/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/Ubuntu%2012.04%20LTS%20%5fPrecise%20Pangolin%5f%20-%20Release%20amd64%20(20120425)_dists_precise_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)/ precise/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/Ubuntu%2012.04%20LTS%20%5fPrecise%20Pangolin%5f%20-%20Release%20amd64%20(20120425)_dists_precise_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems


0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 619 not upgraded.
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: No such file or directory
boot-repair is executed in live-session (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, precise, Ubuntu, x86_64)
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit

=================== os-prober:
/dev/sda1:Windows Recovery Environment (loader):Windows:chain
/dev/sda2:Windows 7 (loader):Windows1:chain
/dev/sda5:Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (12.04):Ubuntu:linux

=================== blkid:
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="PQSERVICE" UUID="701C63931C635360" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="SYSTEM RESERVED" UUID="967CF34F7CF3291F" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Acer" UUID="761E26E71E269FDB" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda5: UUID="ab063406-c2b4-49fc-94c7-d91c1592faff" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda6: UUID="49b9ffb8-d013-4b78-9027-09e8ce95682b" TYPE="swap"
/dev/sr0: LABEL="Ubuntu 12.04 LTS amd64" TYPE="iso9660"


1 disks with OS, 3 OS : 1 Linux, 0 MacOS, 2 Windows, 0 unknown type OS.

Windows not detected by os-prober on sda3.
Warning: extended partition does not start at a cylinder boundary.
DOS and Linux will interpret the contents differently.


=================== sda5/etc/default/grub :

# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT="Windows Recovery Environment (loader) (on /dev/sda1)"
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"





=================== sda5/etc/grub.d/ :
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Aug 15 04:10 grub.d
total 56
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6715 Apr 17 18:20 00_header
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5522 Apr 17 17:57 05_debian_theme
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 7407 May 17 07:21 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6335 Apr 17 18:20 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1588 Nov 27  2011 20_memtest86+
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 7603 Apr 17 18:20 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  214 Apr 17 18:20 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   95 Apr 17 18:20 41_custom
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  483 Apr 17 18:20 README




=================== dmesg | grep EFI :
This live-session is not in EFI-mode.
[    4.095388] EFI Variables Facility v0.08 2004-May-17



=================== PARTITIONS & DISKS:
sda1    : sda,  not-sepboot,    no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    is-os,  not--efi--part, part-has-no-fstab,  part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, BOOTMGR,    no-grldr,   BOOT/BCD,   nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   not-far,    /mnt/boot-sav/sda1.
sda2    : sda,  not-sepboot,    no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    is-os,  not--efi--part, part-has-no-fstab,  part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    no-grldr,   Boot/BCD,   nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   not-far,    /mnt/boot-sav/sda2.
sda3    : sda,  not-sepboot,    no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    is-os,  not--efi--part, part-has-no-fstab,  part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    no-grldr,   no-b-bcd,   nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   farbios,    /mnt/boot-sav/sda3.
sda5    : sda,  not-sepboot,    grubenv-ok  grub2,  grub-pc,    update-grub,    64, with-boot,  is-os,  not--efi--part, fstab-without-boot, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    no-grldr,   no-b-bcd,   apt-get,    grub-install,   with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   farbios,    /mnt/boot-sav/sda5.

sda : MSDos,    not-GPT,    BIOSboot-not-needed,    has-no-EFIpart,     not-usb,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

=================== parted -l:

Model: ATA WDC WD10EADX-22T (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
1      1049kB  18.9GB  18.9GB  primary   ntfs            diag
2      18.9GB  19.0GB  105MB   primary   ntfs            boot
3      19.0GB  574GB   555GB   primary   ntfs
4      574GB   1000GB  427GB   extended
5      574GB   996GB   423GB   logical   ext4
6      996GB   1000GB  4023MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)




Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
has been opened read-only.


Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!


=================== mount:
/cow on / type overlayfs (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
/dev/sr0 on /cdrom type iso9660 (ro,noatime)
/dev/loop0 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/ubuntu/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=ubuntu)
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda1 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda2 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda3 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda3 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda5 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda5 type ext4 (rw)


=================== ls:
/sys/block/sda (filtered):  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight power queue range removable ro sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5 sda6 size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/sys/block/sr0 (filtered):  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight power queue range removable ro size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/dev (filtered):  autofs block bsg btrfs-control bus cdrom cdrw char console core cpu cpu_dma_latency disk dri dvd dvdrw ecryptfs fb0 fd full fuse hidraw0 hidraw1 hidraw2 hpet input kmsg log mapper mcelog mem net network_latency network_throughput null oldmem port ppp psaux ptmx pts random rfkill rtc rtc0 sda sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5 sda6 sg0 sg1 shm snapshot snd sr0 stderr stdin stdout uinput urandom usbmon0 usbmon1 usbmon2 vga_arbiter zero
ls /dev/mapper:  control
ls /mnt/boot-sav/sda3: Windows Users ubuntu Information Volume System settings.ini Games Riot $RECYCLE.BIN Recovery PSFONTS (x86) Files Program Files Program ProgramData PFiles PerfLogs pagefile.sys OEM Nexon MSOCache MOD01SET7B000G0026.enc MOD01SET0J000N000U.enc hiberfil.sys Game f3ecc2cfc0833c2cbcf0967c extensions e9bbe619e36eafea7b47 Settings and Documents DFU Config.Msi codec-info ce941eaec1e81c8ed35546049f61c3 bootsqm.dat BOOTSECT.BAK boot-sav book Backup1 Backup AI_RecycleBin AcerSW {9AF94B62-0C6B-43AF-ADBD-EBDCD1B729E1} 7281e5cb786c2997988879 {48B4D502-6502-4BC0-85AC-EEAB4B5747B2} 43eac1e30085fa141b7d5b41 2dc9fa325b4bf2cad9e6b0031690 09aa5e920fb2bffe9bd3 03d4f85f9233980bfda4d9c6

=================== df -Th:

Filesystem     Type       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/cow           overlayfs  1.9G  388M  1.5G  21% /
udev           devtmpfs   1.8G   12K  1.8G   1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs      741M  820K  740M   1% /run
/dev/sr0       iso9660    1.6G  1.6G     0 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop0     squashfs   1.5G  1.5G     0 100% /rofs
tmpfs          tmpfs      1.9G   32K  1.9G   1% /tmp
none           tmpfs      5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none           tmpfs      1.9G  208K  1.9G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda1      fuseblk     18G   12G  6.3G  65% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sda2      fuseblk    100M   26M   75M  26% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sda3      fuseblk    517G  110G  408G  22% /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
/dev/sda5      ext4       394G  9.4G  365G   3% /mnt/boot-sav/sda5

=================== fdisk -l:

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x30b99ef2

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    36866047    18432000   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2   *    36866048    37070847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        37070848  1120164979   541547066    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4      1120165886  1953523711   416678913    5  Extended
/dev/sda5      1120165888  1945663487   412748800   83  Linux
/dev/sda6      1945665536  1953523711     3929088   82  Linux swap / Solaris


Partition outside the disk detected.

=================== Recommended repair
Recommended-Repair
This setting will reinstall the grub2 of sda5 into the MBR of sda.
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s   fix-windows-boot


Quantity of real Windows: 1
Copied Win boot files from sda2 to sda3

Reinstall the GRUB of sda5 into the MBR of sda
grub-install (GRUB) 1.99-21ubuntu3.1
grub-install --recheck /dev/sda: Installation finished. No error reported.
exit code of grub-install /dev/sda:0

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda5 update-grub
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-29-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows Recovery Environment (loader) on /dev/sda1
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda2
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda3
Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda5/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.
The boot files of [Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk).
```

Can anyone help me :(?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to fix Windows Boot loader , after it Reinstall grub on your Ext4 ubuntu partitions. Follow below links

[Can't boot to Windows anymore after removing Grub on a Netbook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171722/cant-boot-to-windows-anymore-after-removing-grub-on-a-netbook/171812#171812)

[How to reinstall or recover GRUB/MBR on an Intel Mac?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13554/how-to-reinstall-or-recover-grub-mbr-on-an-intel-mac)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: if you follow answers  perfectly ,definitely you will get solution.For More details you can google it.

Comment: The comunity, in which I am an active member, at least on this site, frowns upon simply linking. Should the inked website go down, your answer would not be of much help.